# regular expression to check a line for word and print whole line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this as

```
$str= '</b><b>Tech Fax:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Fax Ext:<br/>
</b><b>Tech Email: </b><a href="mailto:rsurikov@gmail.com">rsurikov@gmail.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=69.93.127.10&amp;output=nice">ns1.linode.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=65.19.178.10&amp;output=nice">ns2.linode.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=75.127.96.10&amp;output=nice">ns3.linode.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=207.192.70.10&amp;output=nice">ns4.linode.com</a><br/>
<b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=109.74.194.10&amp;output=nice">ns5.linode.com</a><br/>
<b>DNSSEC:</b>Unsigned<br/>
<b>Registrar Abuse Contact Email: </b><a href="mailto:abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com">abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com</a><br/>
<b>Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: </b>+1-2013775952<br/>
<b>URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System:<br/>
</b><a href="http://wdprs.internic.net" target="_blank">http://wdprs.internic.net</a>/<br/>
>>>Last update of WHOIS database: 2015-07-01T16:22:28+0000Z<br />
</td><td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="53" rowspan="2">
&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr align="left" valign="top"><td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="639">
&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table><br />
<form name="queryform" method="post" action="/index.php">
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="540" dir="ltr">
<tr><td bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" dir="ltr">
   <tr class="upperrow">
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><font face="Arial" size="+0"><b>Enter any domain name:</b></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="middlerow">
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap">
      <input type="text" name="query" value="" class="queryinput" size="20" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Domain" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lowerrow">
      <td align="right" valign="bottom"></td>
   </tr>
</table>'
```

I need a regular expression in PHP to check the line for Name Server: and then save the whole line for me.
I need $match to be :

```
 <b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=69.93.127.10&amp;output=nice">ns1.linode.com</a><br/>
    <b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=65.19.178.10&amp;output=nice">ns2.linode.com</a><br/>
    <b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=75.127.96.10&amp;output=nice">ns3.linode.com</a><br/>
    <b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=207.192.70.10&amp;output=nice">ns4.linode.com</a><br/>
    <b>Name Server: </b><a href="/index.php?query=109.74.194.10&amp;output=nice">ns5.linode.com</a><br/>
```

also there are not always 4 line included "Name Server:" in $str , sometimes its two line and some times its 5 and that's the problem for the regular expression I wrote and here it is :

```
/Name Server[^:]*:\s*(.*)\s(.*)/i
```

Comment: any suggestion how to do that ? I'm PHP beginner :) ...

Comment: What do you want to extract exactly? the href content and the domain name?

Comment: I only need the DNS name which is ns1.linode.com ns2.linode.com ns3.linode.com ns4.linode.com ns5.linode.com, But I have a code to extract them from html tags. All I need is to have those line in a variable...

Comment: Yes, the code works with DOM, But before I use the code I need to have those lines out of the string....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument in combination with DOMXPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//b[text()="Name Server: "]/following-sibling::a[1]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The xpath query means:

```
//                        # anywhere in the DOM tree
b                         # a b tag
[text()="Name Server: "]  # condition: the text content must be "Name Server: "
/following-sibling::a[1]  # the first following "a" tag
```

Comment: WoW !!!! Its works great ! :) It print them like that ns.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com ks392904.kimsufi.com, any way to have each one of them in separate line ?

Comment: @pco: I think you will find yourself how to do that.

Comment: a little bit more help will be appreciated :). I'm re-writing the code someone else wrote many times ago and that is the way I'm learning PHP...

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the [preg_match_all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function. Take the following short script as an example:

```
<?php

$a = "abc\ndef\naaa\naba\nxyz";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/a.*/", $a, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

which will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => aaa
            [2] => aba
        )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking it is a bad idea to try and search/parse html with regex. However, if you insist and are sure that the html wont vary much from what you posted above you can do:

```
/^(?:<b>Name Server: <\/b><a href="\/index.php\?query=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\&amp;output=nice">\w+\.\w+\.\w+<\/a><br\/>.)+^/sm
```

You can see how this works here: https://regex101.com/r/dU6gH4/1